# Find closest country based on lat long coordinates

Tags: r, geospatial

I have many coastal coordinates. Now I want to find the country of the coordinates. Because some of the coordinates are (just) in the sea, I need some kind of nearest country code. The code I have used now gives many coordinates without output (NA) see below. Anyone who can help me?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You may find more help at https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.